# Get “Terminated due to Memory error” message pop up in iOS 8

Tags: ios, memory, xcode6

I am developing in ios 8.

After I run the application in iPhone,after sometime my app crashes and there is a pop up on Xcode saying that terminated due to memory error.There is no memory warning message in the log.Even I have put breakpoints on `(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` methods in all view controllers but none them were fired.

I have used a custom library to download images and store them in cache memory.
I am not the reason for the crash in my application.There are some `NSLayoutConstraint` breaks in some of the `UIDesigns` of my application.I wonder if the constraint breaks might be the reason for this unusual crash.
I have also disable the zombie in xcode but still the application crashes giving the pop up message

Anybody can help me? I am not getting the exact reason for the crash.

Comment: Have you checked the crashlogs.

Comment: Yes I checked the crash logs.There was no memory warning message.

Comment: try to put a breakpoint in your app delegate:
    `- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application`
and free up as much memory as possible (maybe clear image cache or something...)

Comment: check the cache folder of the app.if it comprises of many high sized images cached by the image library.

Comment: Thanks.Even there are a lot of autolayout constraint breaks.I wonder if they are the reason.It says message from the debugges-terminating app due to memory error

Comment: I wonder if you could tell me how to check the cache folder @Sulabh

Comment: check your exception write this:     NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
 in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and this method to read the exception void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ caused by %@", exception.name, exception.reason];
    NSLog(@"%@%@", errorMessage, [exception callStackSymbols]]);
} let us know

Comment: I removed all the autolayout constraint breaks.It reduced.But still the error is not solved..It is occuring but the frequency of crash has reduced.None of the (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning are getting fired.